# Как организовать передачу и обработку параметров в Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Как передавать параметры в свой скрипт и потом их обрабатывать, как например в *slick* слайдере?

Код:

```
$('.single-item').slick({параметр1: 1,параметр2: 2,});
```

Answer (score 1):

Не очень конкретный вопрос. Но например если в свой класс то можно так

```
class MyClass{
  constructor(options) {
    this.height = options.height;
    this.width = options.width;
 }
}
let myVar = new MyClass({height: '10px', width: '20px'})
```

Если же вы хотите сделать свой плагин для jQuery то

```
$.fn.greenify = function(options) {
    this.css( 'color', options.color );
};

$( "a" ).greenify({color:'green'});
```

Comment: Я бы добавил ещё значения по умолчанию `this.height = options.height || "100%"; // какое-то захардкоженное значение`